# Is there a way to avoid the subqueries with a query has three subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have this query and it works great (not sure) about performance

```
SELECT ssp.product_id, p.price
FROM system_step_product AS ssp
JOIN product AS p ON p.product_id=ssp.product_id 
WHERE ssp.system_id = 14
AND ssp.step_number = (
  SELECT step_number
  FROM system_step_product
  WHERE system_id = '14'
  AND step_number > (
    SELECT step_number
    FROM system_step_product
    WHERE system_id = '14'
    AND product_id = '81'
    ORDER BY step_number ASC
    LIMIT 1
  )  
  ORDER BY step_number ASC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

If I have to go about it with this approach I will but i was wondering if anyone can think of a better way of executing this query

Comment: Is it possible to use join ? Which is more efficient than inner queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two limit clauses make the join statement require the `row_number() OVER ()` window function, which is not available in MySQL. And even that, would likely make your query less efficient than it currently is.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but maybe you can build from it.

```
select 
        ssp.product_id, 
        p.price 
    from 
        system_step_product as ssp 
    join 
        product as p 
        on p.product_id = ssp.product_id        
    left join
        ( select min(step_number) as min_step_number
          from system_step_product
          where system_id = '14'
            and product_id = '81'
        ) minstep
        on minstep.min_step_number = ssp.step_number
    where
        minstep.min_step_number is null and
        ssp.system_id = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

w/o looking at the logic you can get rid of the order/limit 1 stuff:

```
    SELECT ssp.product_id, p.price
    FROM system_step_product AS ssp
    JOIN product AS p ON p.product_id=ssp.product_id 
    WHERE ssp.system_id = 14
    AND ssp.step_number = (
        SELECT MIN(step_number)
        FROM system_step_product
        WHERE system_id = '14'
        AND step_number > (
            SELECT MIN(step_number)
            FROM system_step_product
            WHERE system_id = '14'
            AND product_id = '81'
        )
    )
```

there's probably a much nicer way to accomplish what you're doing and ditch inner queries, but hard to say w/o understanding the goal for the query.

plus... define 'better' :)